# RichTextBox text after drop event

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, dependency-properties

I have a custom RichTextBox where the Text property contains the text as plain text and a Dependency property 'Rtf' contains the text as rtf. When I move the text by drag/drop I want to update this Rtf property after the drop. For example when I move the text from a RichTextBox to a TextBox, I'm looking for an event after a succesfull drop in the TextBox. Is there any event for this purpose?

Simple example:

```
public class RichTextBox : System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox
{
    static RichTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(RichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(RichTextBox)));
    }

 public string Rtf
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(RtfProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RtfProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RtfProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Rtf", typeof(string), typeof(RichTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnRtfPropertyChanged));
}
```

Comment: How would you implement drag/drop behavior ?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using default drag drop.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such event, we use the MouseUp() events for this case.

Comment: Can you explain, why the `Drop` Event is not suitable for your case? Make sure to register your handler in a way to handle events even if they where already marked as handled... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-open-a-file-that-is-dropped-on-a-richtextbox-control

Comment: @grek40 because I don't need the Drop on the RichTextBox but I want to know when the text was dropped on the TextBox (from the RichTextBox)

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Just initiate the DragDrop with an explicit `DataObject` and `SetData(Type, Object)` for types `DataFormats.Text` and `DataFormats.Rtf` with appropriate data. Then the drop target can decide which data format to accept for the drop event. Your source shouldn't care about what the target does as soon as it finished the job of providing appropriate data.